# Does Cordova support Tizen?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, tizen

I'm interested if I can build an app for Tizen TV with Ionic?
I've searched the web and found Tizen documentations for older versions of Cordova,but there was no docs for current version.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check bottom links from:

https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/Cordova

a sample project worth to be shared

Comment: thanks for an answer,but is it possible to use that widget in ionic?

Answer (score 0):

samsung tv has supported cordova,actually you can refer to following:
https://github.com/Samsung/cordova-sectv-tizen.
And it depend on your application's requirement.If you need to access the device api, you should use webapis provided by samsung tv.